# I defined a function (using python) and when I use it, it returns me IndentationError

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the buggy [part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRSZV.png):

```
def sort_image(path1,path2=None):
    import os
    import shutil
    path_list=[]
    if path2 is None:
        for i in range(1,len(os.listdir(path1))+1):
            pathh_temp = path1 + '/' + '%d_Hazy.bmp'%(i)
            path_list.append(pathh_temp)

    else:
        list_i = os.listdir(path1)
        for i in list_i:
            if i.find('Imagei') != -1:
                shutil.move(path1+'/'+i, path2+'/' + i)
            else:
                continue
        for i in range(1,len(os.listdir(path2))+1):
            pathi_temp = path2+ '/' + '%d_Image_.bmp'%(i)
            path_list.append(pathi_temp)

    return path_list
```

When I try to call the function, I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyaNW.png):

```
File "build_data.py", line 25
   path_list.append(pathh_temp)
                              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

When I run the same code **seperately in terminal**, it runs correctly. Why? How can I fix this error?

Comment: All code needs to be posted here directly as text.

Answer (score 0):

welcome on Stack Overflow!

First thing, be helpful with the people who will read your question: always copy-paste your relevant code directly in the question (I've done that for you this time ;) ).

Coming to your question, I think you have a typo at line 29:

```
list_i = os.listdir(path1)
```

without the colon ':' at the end.

The code below works for me (although you didn't tell what your code is supposed to do: I'm guessing by reading it):

```
def sort_image(path1,path2=None):
    import os
    import shutil
    path_list=[]
    if path2 is None:
        for i in range(1,len(os.listdir(path1))+1):
            pathh_temp = path1 + '/' + '%d_Hazy.bmp'%(i)
            path_list.append(pathh_temp)

    else:
        list_i = os.listdir(path1)
        for i in list_i:
            if i.find('Image') != -1:
                shutil.move(path1+'/'+i, path2+'/' + i)
            else:
                continue
        for i in range(1,len(os.listdir(path2))+1):
            pathi_temp = path2+ '/' + '%d_Image_.bmp'%(i)
            path_list.append(pathi_temp)

    return path_list
```

Try and see if it works!